# What's wrong with my ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im trying to create an ajax call through the following code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/',
        method: 'GET',
        data: data
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("doesn't work");
    })
```

Controller:

```
if request.xhr?
  return "hello"
end
```

The ajax call works but the response I get is a html page and not the actual string "hello". Why is that?

Comment: in your `if`'s body you need to render a json(if that's what you want) response: `render json: { body: 'hello' }`, or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of an controller action is always ignored by Rails. To respond something to the client (browser), you have to use `render` or one of its derivatives (`head`, `redirect_to`, `send_file`, `send_data`).

```
if request.xhr?
  render plain: "hello"
end
```